# Will seeing a Muggle death allow one to see Thestrals?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures

Will seeing a Muggle death allow one to see Thestrals? Can anyone provide canon examples either way?

Comment: I think the first question is do you have to be a wizard to see a thestral at all

Comment: @user13267 That question has been asked separately: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64789/3567

Answer (score 5):

I think any death allows you to see a Thestral. I mean when Luna explains it, she never names you having to see a specific creature dying, wizard or non wizard.

[You can see here](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0001007/quotes). It is also in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

> Harry Potter: [about the Thestrals] So why can't the others see them?
>
> Luna Lovegood: **The only people who can see them are those who've seen
>   death.**  Harry Potter: So, you've known someone who died?
>
> Luna Lovegood: My mum. She was quite an extraordinary witch, but she did
>   like to experiment, and one day, one of her spells went badly wrong. I
>   was nine.
>
> Harry Potter: I'm sorry.
>
> Luna Lovegood: Yes, it was rather
>   horrible. I still feel very sad about it sometimes. But I've still got
>   Dad.

All the people that saw them in the books saw wizards die, but that does not mean that it is a rule. You need to see death.

***It probably has to be a human death.***

As what the user Angew said it probably has to be a human death as well. Harry lived in a cupboard for a while and probably saw loads of bugs die. Also, Luna said people, so that seems self explanatory. Muggles and Wizards are both people.

Comment: I'd say it actually has to be human death, right? I guess most people have squashed at least one fly or mosquito in their lives...