# Into which house was Rowling sorted?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, jk-rowling, sorting-hat

I've heard that JKR is both a Gryffindor and a Hufflepuff, so I'm not sure what to believe.

**Has J. K. Rowling revealed the house into which she was sorted, and has her answer been *consistent*?**

Comment: She has said that she values courage above all else but she has said that Hufflepuff is her favourite (or favourite after Gryffindor it might be).

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off topic as it never happened in the book or movies. This is a question about a real world person, and how she would fit in a fictional world. Even if J.K. had stated a preference, it would be trivia. (Hate to be the spoil-sport, but once we start entertaining this line of thought, it gets harder to draw the line. ["The line must be drawn here!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tleSnj4OD0g)

Comment: Definitely not Ravenclaw. A Ravenclaw wouldn't leave as many plot holes xD

Comment: @MeatTrademark Behind-the-scenes and **fandom information** are [explicitly on-topic according to the help centre](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MeatTrademark I am afraid you are mistaken about whether fandom information (or "trivia" as you call it) is on topic - it actually _is_ on topic. please see [why-is-fandom-information-treated-as-if-it-werent-on-topic?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9529/why-is-fandom-information-treated-as-if-it-werent-on-topic) Thank you. :)

Comment: @RedCaio Fair enough.

Comment: By what metric? Are you asking for her opinion in the world of fiction,  if which she controls and has final say?  Or the sorting algorithm that runs on Pottermore?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Well she explicitly confirmed that she cheated, which is pretty interesting in itself.

Comment: I haven't done any research on what house she is in but my friend told me she is in Hufflepuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### She was a Hufflepuff pre-Pottermore (based on a fan-made quiz), and a Gryffindor through Pottermore. She considers herself a Gryffindor.

In 2000, J.K. Rowling took a random fan-made sorting quiz that she stumbled across while trying to understand what "the internet" was. She got Hufflepuff.

> *The Internet! Twice I've been on the internet. Friends of mine were telling me what's on there and I'd never gone looking before. First time, I thought I was never coming back, it's too scary. Some of the stuff that's out there is very weird. Second time I went in there **someone had set up an unofficial fan site where you can be sorted, they have a Sorting Hat, and I was Hufflepuff. I wasn't that pleased! If anyone's meant to be Gryffindor, it's me.***
>
> <sub>[Mzimba, Lizo. Transcript of interview with J.K. Rowling, BBC Newsround, Fall 2000](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/fall00-bbc-newsround.html)</sub>

Eleven years later she made her own quiz, so she could get the house that she wanted.

> **Scholastic:** We polled some of your fans and we asked them what question they most wanted you to answer. Close to 40,000 people voted and the question they selected with 40 percent of the vote: Which Pottermore House are you in?
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** *Well as I say, I know how it works. So I logged on, and I’m now on Pottermore as a regular user – that’s how I go check what’s going on – although I’m not going to give my user name. **So I went through the Sorting, and I am a Gryffindor.** But I had a moment as I clicked the answer to the last question – and bear in mind, I wrote the questions – I thought, “Hey, I’m not sure if I’ve answered to get Gryffindor.” I answered them completely honestly, and I knew that I’d answered a couple for different Houses so I thought, “I wonder how they’re going to work this out.” Yes, I am in Gryffindor.*
>
> <sub>[Scholastic Harry Potter Reading Club webchat](https://www.snitchseeker.com/harry-potter-news/jk-rowling-full-harry-potter-reading-club-webchat-discussion-transcript-now-available-91349/)</sub>

Comment: I don't think we can say "She **was** a Hufflepuff" because some random fan-made quiz said so. It's certainly possible that on the Pottermore site she, like Harry, had some influence over her sorting into Griffindor.

Comment: @Blackwood - The OP said "*I've heard that JKR is both a Gryffindor and a Hufflepuff*". This is the source of that rumor.

Comment: [Here](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1000-aol-chat.htm) is another early interview where Rowling said that she *"suspect[s] they might want to put me in Ravenclaw."*

Answer (score 17):

J.K. Rowling was Sorted to [Gryffindor.](http://www.hypable.com/jk-rowling-pottermore-house/).

> I logged on, I’m now on Pottermore as a regular user. That’s how I check what’s going on – even though I’m not going to give my username. I went through the sorting. I had a moment… I thought, **‘Hey, I’m not sure if I answered the questions, I answered honestly, to get me into Gryffindor.’ But yes, I am in Gryffindor.”**

Comment: Lol, I bet she knew how to answer so that she'd get into Gryffindor.

Comment: She cheated. That seems very Slytherin...

Comment: @Richard -- Thanks for improving my answer by including the actual quote -- much appreciation! :

Comment: Considering the link ibid commented on the answer below, it looks like she basically pulled a Harry and chose Gryffindor by going "Not Hufflepuff, not Hufflepuff".

Comment: It appears that we both used different transcripts of the same interview, and thus have somewhat different quotes. I'm too lazy to watch the original to see which is more accurate.

Comment: @Valorum Spot on!

Answer (score 11):

[Rowling reveals in an 1999 interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1099-connectiontransc2.htm) that she isn't a wizard:

> Am I a Muggle? Yes, I am definitely a Muggle.
>
> A Muggle with abnormal amount - er - of knowledge about the wizarding world.

Her answers about believing in magic also confirm that she's a Muggle.  First in [another 1999 interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/0399-barnesandnoble.html):

> *[…] Did you believe in fairies and magic?*
>
> **I don't believe in magic in the sense that I write about it,** but I do believe that extraordinary things can happen in the world for which we don't yet have an explanation.  […]

Then confirmed in [a 2003 interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2003/0626-alberthall-fry.htm):

> **I really don’t in magic the way that it appears in book.** I could be slightly corny and say I do believe in other kinds of magic; the magic of the imagination for example, and love, but **magic as in waving a wand - no**. I’d love to believe in it but I’m afraid I can’t.

Thus, J. K. Rowling isn't permitted to go to Hogwarts and won't be sorted to a house.

Comment: Maybe she's been to Hogwarts, and that's why she knows so much about it.

Comment: Clever, but you can go to [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/news/sorting-returns-to-pottermore) to be sorted, even if you're a muggle.

Comment: Then can you explain [this](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/622120565130797056)?

Comment: @Valorum - Pottermore didn't launch for another twelve or so years.

Comment: @ibid - So she had to wait a while then?

Comment: @Valorum - She [relied on some of the off-brand knock-offs](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/fall00-bbc-newsround.html) while waiting.

Comment: @ibid - I expect she sued the living crap out of that site a few years later :-)

Comment: @b_jonas - This was said in response to a question on if she was Wiccan, not if she was the HP style of magical.

Comment: @ibid He certainly isn't Wiccan, as confirmed by http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2003/0620-dateline-couric.htm (search "occult"), but "Muggle" could refer to either.  In any case, I'll add some quotes to my answer to make it clear that she claims to be a Muggle.

Comment: @b_jonas - I am still unconvinced. One need not believe in magic to be a wizard. You could say that Harry didn't believe in magic until Hagrid showed up, but he wasn't a Muggle.

Comment: @ibid Well sure, but Harry (and Tom Riddle and all the other Muggle-born students too) already believed in magic by the time they arrived in Hogwarts and got sorted.  J. K. Rowling lives in Britain, so if she was a wizard, she'd know by now from the Hogwarts invitation level.

Comment: @b_jonas - She had assumed the letter was a joke and threw it out, due to her staunch non-belief in magic.

Answer (score 7):

The 2014 UK edition of the books (which I have) contain a 'Harry Potter factfile' at the end of *Goblet of Fire*. It includes this nugget.

> Of all the Hogwarts houses, Joanne would want to be in Gryffindor. "That is not to say I would be there. I think there is a good bit of Hufflepuff in me."

Comment: Interesting, but perhaps not an answer in itself.